# POSTing httpWebRequest to HttpListener

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httplistener

I'm starting to implement a basic C# server which will handle POSTs and GETs.

I have the following:

```
private static HttpListener listener;

private static void CreateListener()
{
    listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:1234/");
    listener.Start();
    listener.BeginGetContext(Process, listener);
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
}
private static void Process(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
    listener.BeginGetContext(Process, listener);
    Console.WriteLine(context);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Tried to test it with a basic `httpWebRequest`:

```
private static void Post(string webAddress)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddress);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("Some POSTed Data");
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateListener();
    Post("http://localhost:1234/");
    Console.WriteLine("Got here!!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to trigger the `Process` function. Why is that?

Comment: Con't until a connection is received from client.  So a request is needed from client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` to send request to server and get response.

You can find information about that here in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx)